# upgrading to OS X El Capitan does not resume after reboot

Tags: macos, osx-el-capitan

I downloaded El Capitan successfully. After download, I clicked "Install OS X El Capitan.app" and started installing. I accept terms and conditions. I chose my ssd disk to install. it asked my password, I entered. It started a preparation, and said "Preparing to Install". after several seconds, It said "Ready to Install" and there is a button at bottom to restart computer. when I click this button, it restarts computer. after reboot, I enter first my pgp password (I have Symantec PGP desktop encryption), then open login screen of OS X. I enter my OS X password, then pc opens. and, installation does not resume. it still uses my old OS (mavericks), and when I click "Install OS X El Capitan.app", it does same things again. do I miss some steps ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You'll need to disable your third party disk encryption for the install to work. The install process boots the machine from a clean OS image, and writes to the disk from there. The clean OS image doesn't contain your third party disk encryption software, so it can't write to your disk to do the install. So it fails and ends up rebooting you normally instead.

Answer (score 2):

Symantec Encryption Desktop does not support El Capitan yet.  You will need to decrypt your system and uninstall PGP before you can upgrade to El Capitan.

Rather than open yourself to that vulnerability, I suggest waiting for an update for the application from Symantec.  They just released an update that adds Windows 10 support a week ago, hopefully OS X 10.11 support will be forthcoming soon.

Source: I'm currently deploying this WDE solution for my employer.

Comment: you might want to quote [this too](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH174563.html)